# How to enable custom test discovery with unittest while using xmlrunner

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

Im trying to use custom test discovery while using xmlrunner to report my test results in XML format. Could someone kindly explain to me how I can use `unittest.TestLoader().discover()` properly? Ive tried the following at the end of file `test.py`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     with open('output.xml', 'wb') as output:
         unittest.main(
             testRunner=xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output=output),
             failfast=False, buffer=False, catchbreak=False, exit=False, 
             testLoader=unittest.TestLoader().discover('.', pattern = "*_test.py")
         )
```

But this gives the error:

```
File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    failfast=False, buffer=False, catchbreak=False, exit=False, testLoader=unittest.TestLoader().discover('.', pattern = "*_test.py"))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/main.py", line 93, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/main.py", line 140, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/main.py", line 144, in createTests
    self.test = self.testLoader.loadTestsFromModule(self.module)
AttributeError: 'TestSuite' object has no attribute 'loadTestsFromModule'
```

If I run without the testLoader argument and with the module argument set to None, the test discovery runs but with the default settings which is not what I want.

All the answers I've found thus far pertain to the command line such as `python –m unittest discover -p "test*.py" ...` which is not what I'm looking for. I would appreciate an in-code solution as suggested by the first code snippet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and ended up with this solution:

```
test_results = xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output="xml_test_result").run(unittest.TestLoader().discover("./test", "*_test.py"))
```